# VS2013 Browser Link "The controller for path '/9ac086a69364466a841e03e001f946fd/arterySignalR/ping' could not be found."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, visual-studio-2013

Since updating to VS2013, we receive this error when running our (MCV4) web app:

```
The controller for path '/9ac086a69364466a841e03e001f946fd/arterySignalR/ping' could not be found.
```

I know that it relates to browser link although i'm not sure what we need to do to make it work correctly. Is there some configuration change we need to make to support this new feature?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I disabled browser link.  Second #4 at this link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

Comment: The button for disabling Browser Link is on the "Standard" toolbar

Comment: Search for a "refresh" arrow next to the solution configuration (Visual Studio 2013 Update 2)

Answer (score 14):

If you would like the benefit of Browser Link but don't want the missing controller path exceptions, you can add an ignore regex to your route collection. This is what I did:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

#if DEBUG
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*browserlink}", new { browserlink = @".*/arterySignalR/ping" });
#endif

    //...
}
```

The regex technique is courtesy of [this Phil Haack post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx/).

Comment: what is the benefit of using Browser Link in VS2015

Answer (score 8):

On VS2013 @Todd's solution didn't work for me, so I made my own.
Hope it saves you some time.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
#if DEBUG
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*browserlink}", new { browserlink = @".*__browserLink.*" });
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to your root `web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 5):

This happens to be a known issue with SignalR and has been fixed in SignalR 2.0.1 and 1.1.5:

2.0.1: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2569 (not yet released)
1.1.5: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2570 (not yet released)

Long story short, nothing you can do to change it, should just wait for the next release of browser link which has a newer version of SignalR.

Comment: Is there any fix to this issue yet or any way to manually update the necessary files?

Comment: Sorry but no :( you'll have to wait for a new release of browser link that incorporates the new SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

Had in VS2013, after some project nuget package updates.

Cleaned the solution, closed VS and IISExpress from try and resolved