# arterySignalR/ping MVC4 was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4, C#, Entity framework with repository pattern and I installed the Elmah nuget package. I have set the Elmah to send email when application error appear and since that I receive this:

> System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/3582be999d2646eca85b82b5302fc0af/arterySignalR/ping' was not found or does not implement IController.
>
> Generated: Tue, 05 Nov 2013 14:43:21 GMT System.Web.HttpException
>   (0x80004005): The controller for path
>   '/3582be999d2646eca85b82b5302fc0af/arterySignalR/ping' was not found
>   or does not implement IController.    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I dont know why I receive that error, I even don't know what arterySignalR/ping is and I want to know if someone of you know the solution to solve that.

Thank you very much,

Karine

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2013 Browser Link "The controller for path '/9ac086a69364466a841e03e001f946fd/arterySignalR/ping' could not be found."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484849/vs2013-browser-link-the-controller-for-path-9ac086a69364466a841e03e001f946fd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a 404 Error that has been picked up by ELMAH.  Someone requested that url from your website but as it does not exist it generated the 404 error.

If you do not know what `arterySignalR/ping` is, then you can simply ignore it.  It could be simple as someone mistyping the website url.  If the error is repeating continuously, then it could indicate a problem with a script/webpage or another application which may warrant attention.

Comment: Having this issue. Running on localhost. Using MVC5. SignalR is not installed.

Comment: The error is due to a new feature in VS2013 (browser link) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484849/vs2013-browser-link-the-controller-for-path-9ac086a69364466a841e03e001f946fd