# Where are these poll requests from SignalR coming from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, durandal, single-page-application

I have a SPA application using Durandal.

My program starts to have a http request periodically:

```
http://localhost:1551/f9750d8f8aa54265835e72d56d23144a/arterySignalR/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAACM1YyjLngEiQsL54ET%2B%2FqwAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAAAyZZfHz09psv64kIgPPwQNAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAABMZImCidzdmb21ehxuGD4IoAAAAbazfW7CYR7y7HKb8JPt9ZH9b6fUDlZao60kBG662Vy%2Fb0IHwkwidthQAAAA1qSqnsCOheiNyXiINEyBPBAkqVg%3D%3D&messageId=d-79160814-B%2C0%7CC%2C4%7CD%2C0&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A2690%2F&browserName=Firefox&tid=5&_=1391326350868
```

I don't know where does it come from? As I remember I haven't added any reference to SignalR or something like.

How can I check what part of my code is generating this request? and then remove it maybe.

The technologies I'm using are:

- Durandal
- ASP.NET MVC 4.0
- Knockout
- ASP.NET WebApi

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is coming from the [browser link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx) feature in Visual Studio 2013 in the Standard toolbar. It is code that allows Visual Studio to interact with browsers running the code, and should only show up when running it in debug mode.

To disable it (until the fix to the issue is made live in [an upcoming update](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2569)), follow the directions in #4 of [the msdn page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx) to disable it:

1. Uncheck "Enable Browser Link" in the Browser Link menu item
2. Set appSetting "vs:EnableBrowserLink" to "false" in web.config or debug=false.

Or you can just ignore it. It wont do any harm, will only happen locally, and should be fixed soon.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19484849/51) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19917595/51).

Comment: Thanks, as a matter of fact it exactly came after I've upgraded to Visual Sutdio 2013

Comment: Exactly what I needed to get rid of the network traffic clutter -- thank you!

Comment: This helps to have real-time updates done in the files. Example, if you update a CSS, it reflects changes immediately. Unless you want this feature, turning off Browser link helps remove the network request clutters.

Comment: can we enable this feature in production in IIS for my app?

Comment: I'm still  getting this in visual studio 2015. After leaving a debug session running for 24 hours (the web app has a 5 second heartbeat) visual studio becomes slow and affects the whole machine.