# System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/__browserLink/requestData/[Guid]' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I run my program in my development machine I get this exception.

System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/__browserLink/requestData/e6519371239847088c9c556879ce2765' was not found or does not implement IController.

Also my Session object does not maintain state - it keeps be set to null.
What is going on? The exception does not identify where the problem is.

This question is different to a similar question as it has nothing to do with Signal R, AND I am having a problem with Session State which is not the case in the other question. If you downvoted thinking this is a duplicate then please revert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS2013 Browser Link "The controller for path '/9ac086a69364466a841e03e001f946fd/arterySignalR/ping' could not be found."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484849/vs2013-browser-link-the-controller-for-path-9ac086a69364466a841e03e001f946fd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a problem with your Visual Studio Setup.

Next to the "Start" button in the toolbar is a "Reload" icon. Click on the dropdown icon next to it and uncheck "Enable browser link".

[image: VS2015 - Enable Browser Link]

Comment: That gets rid of the exception (hence uptick). However I still have a problem with the Session State being nullified after each postback.

Comment: Maybe you can move the issue with the Session State to its own question, because it does not match the current question title.

Comment: I thought the 2 might be related. It is unusual to switch off the browser link I would have thought.